# Assigning a variable to an incremented label name

Tags: python, variables, increment

I'm a little out of touch with programming at the moment and would like to ask for advice on this matter. My question is whether it is possible to assign a changing variable (e.g. 2,3,4) to an incremented variable name (e.g. file1, file2...etc) in a loop?

If so, how can I go about doing that?

I have a segment of a script below that I have been trying to implement the aforementioned function:

```
var=0
IDnumber=1
for i in range (5):
    Sample_mean=df.iloc[[var,var+1]].mean(axis=0) #calculating mean from two rows in pandas dataframe. Sample_mean is the numerical variable.
    print ("mean of the samples at timepoint 1=")
    print (Sample_mean)
    var_for_row=var_for_row+2
    Sample_mean=df.iloc[[var_for_row,var_for_row+1]].mean(axis=0) 
    print ("mean of the samples at timepoint 2=")
    print (Sample_mean)
    label='file_%d'%(IDnumber,) #I am incrementing the variable label here
    label=str(label)
    global label #This is to avoid the NameError: global name 'pt_1' is not defined error. However, I still get the error.
    label=Sample_mean
    var_for_row+=2
    print 'var_for_row=%s'%var_for_row
    IDnumber+=1
    print file_1 #Error occurs at this line
```

I tried the code above but I get the error `NameError: global name 'file_1' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot increment a "name" of a variables. Use `list` to store multiple values.

You can increment the "text" that a variable holds if you know the pattern.

```
pat = 'file_{}'
myFiles = []
for n in range(4):
    myFiles.append(pat.format(n))
    print ( myFiles[-1])

print(myFiles)
```

Output:

```
file_0
file_1
file_2
file_3
['file_0', 'file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3']
```

This here:

```
label='file_%d'%(5,) #I am incrementing the variable label here
# label=str(label) # not needed at all - it is already a string
```

is the same as

```
label = 'file_{}'.format(5) # or f'file_{5}' for python3.something
```

See:

- [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)
- [format-string-syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)
- [format-specification-mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

for advanced formatting options.